# React Native: store array of emails in AsyncStorage after successful login

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to store an array of email addresses in my Async Storage. Think of it as "recently used accounts" to speed up login on a device that gets used by multiple users

Here's what I've got so far- this gets called after a user successfully logs in:

```
const storeEmail = async (email) => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(email);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("storedEmails", jsonValue);
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
};
```

My problem is that it only ever stores one email. How do I store an array of emails in there, rather than a single email?

I'd also need to avoid duplicates, so would need to check if an email address already exists in the array?

Comment: it sounds like `email` isn't an array, but a single address... please add the array code to your question. For duplicates, you might use `Set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push the array data like shown below. Initially you can fetch data, if its empty than you can initialise empty array and push data into it. If it has data than you may append the email ID uniquely:

```
    const storeEmail = async (email) => {
        try {
            let emailStored = await AsyncStorage.getItem("storedEmails");
            if(emailStored == null || emailStored == undefined){ 
                emailStored = [];
                emailStored = JSON.stringify(emailStored)
            }
            let emails = JSON.parse(emailStored);
            if (emails.indexOf(email) == -1) {
                emails.push(email);
            }
            const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(emails);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("storedEmails", jsonValue);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, I get an error though- "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object" - any idea why that would be?

Comment: Their was just a  minor change. I have edited my answer. Please check now

Answer (score 1):

For AsyncStorage to store some complex types of data structures, such as arrays, objects and other collections, it is recommended that you use [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md), which can help you solve these annoying data conversion operations, and can also read and write data storage synchronously.

```
  import { XStorage } from 'react-native-easy-app';
  import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
  // or import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

   export const RNStorage = {
       token: undefined, 
       dataList: undefined, 
       userInfo: undefined
   };
   
  const initCallback = () => {

       // From now on, you can write or read the variables in RNStorage synchronously
       
       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('token',TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3==') ]
       RNStorage.token = 'TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3=='; 
       
       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({ name:'rufeng', age:30})) ]
       RNStorage.userInfo = {name: 'rufeng', age: 30}; 

       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('dataList',JSON.stringify([{ name:'rufeng', age:30},{ name:'rufeng', age:30}])) ]
       RNStorage.dataList = [{ name:'rufeng', age:30},{ name:'rufeng', age:30}]; 
  };
  
  XStorage.initStorage(RNStorage, AsyncStorage, initCallback);
```